# Is it possible to first enter a command and then choose "run in Terminal" in Quicksilver?

Tags: macos, terminal, quicksilver

Is it possible to first enter a command and then choose "run in Terminal" in Quicksilver?

Is there another way of doing it other than Quicksilver (though I would prefer Quicksilver)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll need to install the Terminal Plugin.

- Run any command from Quicksilver? Just enter text mode (by pressing .), enter your command and choose either the "Run Text Command in Terminal" action (opens a new terminal window and runs the command) or the "Run Command in Shell" action (runs the command in the background and returns the results to Quicksilver)
- Run a script? Just browse to the script and choose the "Run" or "Run in Terminal [...]" actions.

Comment: what does it mean to "browse to the script"? Can you attach some screenshots to show how we can browse to a script. Thank you.